# Click on svg label that has changing class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The tag below has a changing class value so that can not be used to reference the tag. How to locate this tag and preform a click action

```
<div class="x6s0dn4 x78zum5 x1q0g3np xs83m0k"><svg aria-label="Options" class="x1lliihq x1n2onr6 x5n08af" fill="currentColor" height="32" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="32"><title>Options</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="6" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="18" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle></svg></div>
```

Code below worked at one time but the class value changes.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="x6s0dn4 x78zum5 xdt5ytf xl56j7k"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-label="Options"]').click()
```

How could I write this so its not dependant on the class value and still preform the click action?

Comment: Can you share some more of HTML around the `<svg>` node?

Comment: Updated question to include div one level above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the width and height are probably pretty unlikely to change. So you could use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//svg[@aria-label="Options" and @width="32" and @height="32"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the only `svg` on that page with `aria-label="Options"`, you could try this XPath:

`"//svg[@aria-label='Options']"`

```py
driver.find_element("xpath", "//svg[@aria-label='Options']").click()
```